# How do I persist the checkbox status after click event/jQuery/ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following event code that reloads a code section on my page. The problem is that, if the check box is checked, I can't find a way to re-check it after the reload.

```
jQuery(this.el).find('.view_all_future_filter').click(function () {
    TodoNote.view_all_future_filter = jQuery(this).prop('value');
    _this.parent.reload();
})
```

I tried the following, but the check box keeps being reset to unchecked:

```
if(this.view_all_future_filter == "on") {
    this.query_string += '&view_all_future_filter=' + this.view_all_future_filter;
    var show_state = "checked";
} else {
    var show_state = "";
}
this.load();
jQuery('#view_all_future_filter').prop('checked', show_state);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage) to save data and get it after reload content:

```
if (window.sessionStorage) {

    var checkedState = jQuery('#view_all_future_filter').attr('checked');

    sessionStorage.setItem("someCheckboxState", checkedState);
}
```

And when content loaded to page:

```
if (window.sessionStorage) {

    var checkedState = sessionStorage.setItem("someCheckboxState");

    jQuery('#view_all_future_filter').attr('checked', checkedState);
}
```

**Note:** If you are using `jQuery 1.6+` you must change `attr` to [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for boolean properties as `checked`, `disabled` and etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the checkbox status in a cookie. Then, in an onload callback, initialize the checkbox status from the cookie.